# Calling url stored in variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url, redirect

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$to="codieboi@mail.com";
$msg1="done";
$email_subject = "View Cateloge Request";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-MSMail-Priority: High'. "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$email_message .= "Name: ".$_POST['fname']."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['message']."\n";

@mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
$link = the_field('upload_file', $id);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var url="_________";var win = window.open(url, "_blank");win.focus();</script>';
```

I store a url dynamically to the variable "link". I want to open up it in a new tab, once the mail is send. This is the code I have written. I need to place url in the _____________.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store url to variable link, just use it:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var url='". $link."';var win = window.open(url, '_blank');win.focus();</script>";
```